# Fabric.js - How to animate from a sprite sheet

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas, fabricjs, sprite-sheet

**JavaScript syntax:**

```
context.drawImage(img,srcX,srcY,srcWidth,srcHeight,x,y,width,height);
```

In Javascript, if I wanted to animate the following spritesheet, I would simply update `srcX` and `srcY` every animation frame in order to capture segments of the image.

[image]

This results in each frame being clipped and displayed individually onto the `canvas`, which when updated at a fixed frame rate results in fluid sprite animation, like this:

[image]

How can I do this using the "Fabric.js" library?

**Note:** One way to achieve this would be to set `canvasSize = frameSize` so that only one frame can be seen at any given time. Then by moving the image around, different frames can be placed inside the canvas in order to simulate animation. This will not work however with a large canvas, or with variable frame sizes.

Comment: Do you necessarily want to use fabricsj? I mean, this can be achieved using css3 animation alone. http://templates.newsoftdemo.info/steps-animation/

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj: There are a few reasons why I'm not resorting to CSS animations. The following link provides some explanations.
https://css-tricks.com/myth-busting-css-animations-vs-javascript/ ... The game I'm creating is relatively large and requires good performance and flexibility

Comment: Thanks for the informative link :)

Answer (score 1):

Look at this,it does the same thing.

**A walking human figure.
Fabric.js,image animation.**

```js
        var URL = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/M06El.jpg';
        var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
        var positions = {
            topSteps:2,
            leftSteps:4
        };
        canWalk(URL,positions);
        function canWalk(URL,positions){
            var myImage = new Image();
            myImage.src = URL;
    
            myImage.onload = function() {
                var topStep = myImage.naturalHeight/positions.topSteps;
                var leftStep = myImage.naturalWidth/positions.leftSteps;
    
                var docCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
                docCanvas.height = topStep;
                docCanvas.width = leftStep;
                fabricImageFromURL(0,0);
                var y = 0;
                var x = 0;
                setInterval(function(){
                    if(x == positions.leftSteps)
                    {
                        x = 0;
                        y++;
                        if(y==positions.topSteps)
                        {
                            y=0;
                        }
                    }
                    fabricImageFromURL(-y*topStep,-x*leftStep);
                    x++;
                },100);
            };
        }
    
 function fabricImageFromURL(top, left)
 {
  console.log(top, left);
  fabric.Image.fromURL(URL, function (oImg) {
   oImg.set('left', left).set('top',top);
   oImg.hasControls = false;
   oImg.hasBorders  = false;
   oImg.selectable  = false;
   canvas.add(oImg);
   canvas.renderAll();
  }, {"left": 0, "top": 0, "scaleX": 1, "scaleY": 1});
 }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.3/fabric.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice hack way of doing it ;) Unfortunately I'll be using large canvases so this method won't work for me. I was hoping to clip the image from its source.

Comment: @sookie I answered on your question.There has not been told about "clip the image".But in principle it is not difficult.And this is not hacking,this is logic

Comment: My question described using `srcX`, `srcY` (etc) in order to clip each frame from its source. I was looking for an equivalent solution using fabricjs

Answer (score 0):

By default Fabric won't do it. You need to present 'source' properties in fabric.Image object & extend fabric.Image _render method. Original looks this:

```js
/**
     * @private
     * @param {CanvasRenderingContext2D} ctx Context to render on
     * @param {Boolean} noTransform
     */
    _render: function(ctx, noTransform) {
      var x, y, imageMargins = this._findMargins(), elementToDraw;

      x = (noTransform ? this.left : -this.width / 2);
      y = (noTransform ? this.top : -this.height / 2);

      if (this.meetOrSlice === 'slice') {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(x, y, this.width, this.height);
        ctx.clip();
      }

      if (this.isMoving === false && this.resizeFilters.length && this._needsResize()) {
        this._lastScaleX = this.scaleX;
        this._lastScaleY = this.scaleY;
        elementToDraw = this.applyFilters(null, this.resizeFilters, this._filteredEl || this._originalElement, true);
      }
      else {
        elementToDraw = this._element;
      }
      elementToDraw && ctx.drawImage(elementToDraw,
                                     x + imageMargins.marginX,
                                     y + imageMargins.marginY,
                                     imageMargins.width,
                                     imageMargins.height
                                    );

      this._stroke(ctx);
      this._renderStroke(ctx);
    },
```

And you need to change it:

```js
fabric.util.object.extend(fabric.Image.prototype, {
    _render: function(ctx, noTransform) {
        // ...
        
        elementToDraw && ctx.drawImage(
            elementToDraw,
            this.source.x,
            this.source.y,
            this.source.width,
            this.source.height,
            x + imageMargins.marginX,
            y + imageMargins.marginY,
            imageMargins.width,
            imageMargins.height
        );
        this._renderStroke(ctx);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of setting the *clipTo*-function and invoking *setLeft* / *setTop* in a loop. Within the fabric.Image constructor's option you pass the property *clipTo* and tell fabric to cut out a specific part of the image. Then, with *setTop* / *setLeft* inside a loop you trigger repainting and thereby invoking clipTo and at the same time re-position the cut image so it always stays in the same place.

I had the same problem and extracted the logic into two functions. Quick rundown of the options:
**spriteWidth** - width of one animation frame of the sprite
**spriteHeight** - height of one animation frame of the sprite
**totalWidth** - width of the whole sprite image
**totalHeight** - height of the whole sprite image
**animationFrameDuration** - how long one sprite frame should be shown
**startRandom** - if you want to start the animation not right away, but randomly within 1 second
**left** - just like the normal left option of fabric.Image
**top** - just like the normal top option of fabric.Image

Synchronous version (passing the HTMLImageElement):

```
/**
 * @param imgObj HTMLImageElement
 * @param options {
 *                  spriteWidth: number
 *                  spriteHeight: number
 *                  totalWidth: number
 *                  totalHeight: number
 *                  animationFrameDuration: number
 *                  startRandom: boolean (optional)
 *                  left: number (optional)
 *                  top: number (optional)
 *                }
 * @returns fabric.Image
 */
function animateImg(imgObj, options) {
    const left = options.left || 0;
    const top = options.top || 0;
    let x = 0;
    let y = 0;
    const image = new fabric.Image(imgObj, {
        width: options.totalWidth,
        height: options.totalHeight,
        left: left,
        top: top,
        clipTo: ctx => {
            ctx.rect(-x - options.totalWidth / 2, -y - options.totalHeight / 2, options.spriteWidth, options.spriteHeight);
        }
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
        setInterval(() => {
            x = (x - options.spriteWidth) % options.totalWidth;
            if (x === 0) {
                y = (y - options.spriteHeight) % options.totalHeight;
            }
            image.setLeft(x + left);
            image.setTop(y + top);
        }, options.animationFrameDuration)
    }, options.startRandom ? Math.random() * 1000 : 0);
    return image;
}
```

Asynchronous version (passing the image URL):

```
/**
 * @param imgURL string
 * @param options {
 *                  spriteWidth: number
 *                  spriteHeight: number
 *                  totalWidth: number
 *                  totalHeight: number
 *                  animationFrameDuration: number
 *                  startRandom: boolean (optional)
 *                  left: number (optional)
 *                  top: number (optional)
 *                }
 * @param callback (image : fabric.Image) => void
 */
function animateImgFromURL(imgURL, options, callback) {
    const left = options.left || 0;
    const top = options.top || 0;
    let x = 0;
    let y = 0;
    fabric.Image.fromURL(
        imgURL,
        image => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                setInterval(() => {
                    x = (x - options.spriteWidth) % options.totalWidth;
                    if (x === 0) {
                        y = (y - options.spriteHeight) % options.totalHeight;
                    }
                    image.setLeft(x);
                    image.setTop(y);
                }, options.animationFrameDuration)
            }, options.startRandom ? Math.random() * 1000 : 0);
            callback(image);
        }, {
            width: options.totalWidth,
            height: options.totalHeight,
            left: 0,
            top: 0,
            left: left,
            top: top,
            clipTo: ctx => {
                ctx.rect(-x - options.totalWidth / 2, -y - options.totalHeight / 2, options.spriteWidth, options.spriteHeight);
            }
        });
```

Note that the above functions do not rerender the canvas, you have to do that yourself.
You can use the above code like this to animate your sprite two times side by side (once synchronous version, once asynchronous):

```
// Assuming:
// 1. canvas was created
// 2. Sprite is in html with id 'walking'
// 3. Sprite is within folder 'images/walking.jpg'
const img1 = animateImg(document.getElementById('walking'), {
    spriteWidth: 125,
    spriteHeight: 125,
    totalWidth: 500,
    totalHeight: 250,
    startRandom: true,
    animationFrameDuration: 150,
    left: 125,
    top: 0
});
canvas.add(img1);
animateImgFromURL('images/walking.jpg', {
    spriteWidth: 125,
    spriteHeight: 125,
    totalWidth: 500,
    totalHeight: 250,
    startRandom: true,
    animationFrameDuration: 150
}, image => canvas.add(image));
// hacky way of invoking renderAll in a loop:
setInterval(() => canvas.renderAll(), 10);
```